# CUPS-PDF Output Filename Fix

Tags: printer, network-printer, print-server, cups, pdf

I'm using Virtual PDF Printer with cups-pdf package in debian 7.7 wheezy.
I have some problem with output PDF filename.
It's work correctly when I Print .rtf document with wordpad.
But, when I Print .docx document with MS Office 2010 or .txt document with notepad, then output filename has broken.
For example, when I print test.txt file with cups-pdf printer, output filename is "test_-_?????.pdf".
And when I print test.docx file with cups-pdf printer, output filename is "Microsoft_Word_-_test.pdf".

How Can I fix it?